# How do I start udhcpc automatically on startup?

Tags: dhcp

I used the following command:

```
udhcpc -i eth0
```

and configured the `eth0` device to DHCP. 
Now, running `ifconfig` shows me my dynamic IP address.

After I reboot the device, this configuration was gone;

How can I make `udhcpc` start automatically on startup with the above configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you put that line into a startup script inside your network layer configuration, so inside `/etc/sysconfig/network`. In there you probably already have a number of scripts. Take a look around, this is no rocket science. The `man` pages will offer precise information about the different scripts and options.

A more specific answer is only possible with deeper knowledge of the system you are working on.